# Adding .active class to a jQuery slideToggle menu

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have a couple of hidden DIVs on top of my page which should be toggled with a menu. Therefor I'm using a [code from random snippets](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2011/04/10/how-to-hide-show-or-toggle-your-div-with-jquery/) which is quite simple:

Javascript:

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    $("#"+divId).slideToggle();
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:toggleDiv('projekte');">Projekte</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:toggleDiv('mo');">Mo</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Now I'd like to add the class .active to the link whose DIV is visible. I'm not sure how to select that link, can anyone help?

Besides that it would be nice to close another/all other toggled DIV, if there is one visible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
$('ul li a').on('click', function(e) {

    // to keep your link from actually clicking through
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $( '#' + $(this).attr('href') ).slideToggle();

});
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="projekte">Projekte</a></li>
    <li><a href="mo">Mo</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you please confirm that the purpose of `e.preventDefault();` is to remove the default click functionality of anchor so that on clicking it we can stop it's navigation to another page?

Comment: In this case, that's exactly what it's doing.

Comment: What do u mean in this case? Is there any other functionality of `e.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: Sure, different elements have different default onclick behavior. In this case, is preventing a link from directing the browser to an address.

Comment: Cool, don't tell me; tell OP.

Comment: Works fine! The DIVs have the class .overlay. How can I close another .overlay DIV, if there's one visible?

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the code to be a bit more accessible without Javascript enabled

**Javascript**

```
$('ul').find('a').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this); // cache $(this)

    $this.addClass('active');
    $( $this.attr('href') ).slideToggle();

    return false; // prevent anchor click event
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#projekte">Projekte</a></li>
    <li><a href="#mo">Mo</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="projekte">Stuff</div>
<div id="mo">Stuff</div>
```